# there is isuue with mysql command in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

Thanks for your support... there is a problem with my code.
First I get the data from database customer whose fields are firstname and lastname and area_name because the result

Due to the space between the words, there is a confusion when I enter the data into the another database(fb_customer)

```
#!/bin/bash
  
echo "
SELECT 
firstname ,
lastname ,
area_name 
FROM customer
WHERE dateCustomer > DATE_FORMAT(concat(curdate(),' ','00:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ;

" |
    mysql -N -h $host -P $port -u $username -p$password -D $database | 
    awk -F: '{print $0}' | 
    while read line
    do
        tmparray=($line)
        firstname=${tmparray[0]}     
        lastname=${tmparray[1]}     
        area_name=${tmparray[2]}            
         
    echo "
     
     INSERT INTO customer.fb_customer (firstname,lastname,area_name)
     VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$area_name');"  | mysql -N -h $hostL -u $usernameL -p$passwordL -D $databaseL

   
    done
    echo $tmparray
```

Comment: Generating SQL commands through string concatenation is inherently prone to injection attacks. https://bobby-tables.com/ is a good place to start in understanding why it's best abandoned in favor of built-to-purpose tools.

Comment: (back in the day I built a custom SQL client that was designed to be easy to securely use from bash -- supporting bind parameters with NUL-separated values used to fill them in; alas, it was owned by my employer of the time, and I haven't seen anything similarly publicly released since).

Comment: BTW, `while read -r firstname lastname area_name` will get you out of the `tmparray` business, and you can set `IFS` to a variable that's an appropriate delimiter (if your output is separated by tabs, use `IFS=$'\t'` so _only_ tabs split fields and not regular spaces). But again, don't do any of this; use a language with a native SQL library.

Comment: This code cannot handle names containing whitespace -- [Falsehoods about Names – With Examples](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/)

Comment: as currently written there are too many (sub)processes and no actual data to work with; at this point we're left guessing at what the issue may be; I suggest you start with the initial `echo` and verify it's generating the desired output, then add the pipe to `mysql` and verify the results from the `mysql` call, then add the pipe to `awk` and verify results, etc, etc, etc; if you still have problems then update the question to show the step causing issues, making sure to provide the output from the previous command in the pipeline as well as the output from the problematic command